# Unable to set header in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to set header via $.ajax
Jquery Version using : 1.9

Here is my code.

```
var urlSetting = $.ajaxSetup();
urlSetting.crossDomain = true;
urlSetting.dataType = "json";
urlSetting.success = function(){}
urlSetting.type = "POST";
urlSetting.data = urlData;
urlSetting.beforeSend = function (jqxhr) {
 jqxhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
 jqxhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
}   

var urlLoader  = $.ajax(myurl,urlSetting);
```

Problem 2 : it will automatically convert my request type to "OPTIONS".

Request Snapshot
[image]

Comment: You are setting `crossDomain` to `true`. I *believe* it forces jQuery to make a JSONP request, i.e. you cannot modify the headers at all. Try to not set it since it looks like the endpoint enabled CORS anyway.

Comment: Does "thanks" mean it worked? If yes, I can provide my comment as an answer and this question can be marked as solved.

Comment: @FelixKling no it is not solved yet. actually I want it with CORS System.

Comment: As far as I can see, CORS is *already* enabled (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`). But the allowed methods are only `POST` and `OPTIONS`. A JSONP request is *always* `GET`. Doing a "normal" `POST` Ajax request should work perfectly fine.

Comment: So there is no solution for Setting header in CORS requests ?

Comment: No, I'm saying it should work with a normal Ajax request, *because* CORS is enabled. It does *not* work with JSONP. Now I think you are using `$.ajaxSetup` the wrong way. You have to *pass* an object to it. See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/. Also note that its use is not recommend. Just use `$.ajax` normally.